# Error play-services-maps:17.0.1 in Android Studio

Tags: java, android

The following error is happening to me:

```
ERROR: Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs (Gradle sync issues -> Manifest merger failed with multiples erros, see logs)
```

The `AndroidManifest.xml` file says the errors are:

- **Merging Errors: Error: Missing 'package' key attribute on element package at AndroidManifest.xml:33:9-64 play-services-maps:17.0.1 manifest, line 32 Error:**
- **Validation failed, exiting play-services-maps:17.0.1 manifest**

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.google.android.gms.maps" >
    
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14" />
    
        <!-- Include required permissions for Google Maps API to run. -->
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    
        <uses-feature
            android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
            android:required="true" />
    
        <queries>
    
            <!-- Needs to be explicitly declared on Android R+ -->
            <package android:name="com.google.android.apps.maps" />
        </queries>
    
        <application>
    
            <!-- Needs to be explicitly declared on P+ -->
            <uses-library
                android:name="org.apache.http.legacy"
                android:required="false" />
        </application>
    
    </manifest>
```

- `build.gradle (Project: app)`

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    
    android {
        compileSdkVersion 28
        buildToolsVersion "30.0.3"
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.testmaps"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 28
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }
    
    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }
```

Comment: the dependencies of my ```build.gradle (Project: Test Maps)``` file are ```classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.0'```

Answer (score 7):

If you replace `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.1` to `com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0`, your problem will be solved.
Basically you have to use `17.0.0` of `play-services-maps`